# How to properly center a 100% width div in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my website, i've tried putting div inside a div, but i think that's not the proper way to do it. can someone tell me how to have a 100% width but centered like facebook? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ma3y77bt/

Here is the working HTML:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="body-content"></div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

In order to have a fixed header and footer that span the width of the page, you first need to define the dimensions of the body container. To do so, simple apply the following:

```
html, body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Next, you can define the dimensions of the header. We use absolute positioning here to always make sure that the header is on top of all other elements.

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

** Also, by matching the height with the line-height, the content is also vertically aligned.

For the footer, we do the same except align it to the bottom of the page after the body content.

```
.footer {
    postion: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #999;
}
```

Please see the jsfiddle for an example

Answer (score 1):

Simply use, e.g:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/bbdjhb40/)

```
body{
    width:100%; /* <--- make the document content the width of the viewport */
    text-align:center; /* <--- centre the document content */
    margin:0;
}
div{
    margin:0 auto; /** <-- align the content to the centre of the document */
    width:500px; /** <-- width of your content */
}
```

Comment: thanks dude. it works,but how can i have a 100% header and footer but still centered?

Comment: I want my header and footer to have a 100% width,just like facebook. should i put it outside my main div? because my main div has a specified width.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a centered container that is still responsive? If so you can set a `max-width` on the content and then use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it.

The max-width means the container will be 100% wide until 1200px then stop, giving you responsiveness below 1200.

e.g.

```
container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Im not too fond of this answer. Having the max-width at 1200px wouldn't be cross device compatible. For example, what if my screen width is 2560x1600?

Comment: If you are looking for a full width fluid design then of course you wouldn't want to use a max-width. The OP asked to have it centered like facebook which this does.

Comment: Regardless of full width or contained width, I wouldn't suggest absolutely positioning everything like you have as this allows minimal flexibility and is not dynamic. You have set a fixed height on your body, how does this allow for different templates, content etc?

Comment: His question had no specification for fluid design or not. I was going off of a simple approach for desktop devices.